# Find and identify which elements from an array exist in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have an array let's say it looks like this:

```
$arr=array('aa','bb','cc');
```

Now let's say I have a string that looks like any of these:

```
$str='bb';
$str='A_STRING_bb_WITH_SOME_TEXT';
$str='ASTRINGbbWITHSOMETEXT';
$str='A+STRING+bb+WITH+SOME+TEXT';
$str='A STRING bb WITH SOME TEXT';
```

I would like a function that gives me:

```
$r=find_which_one($arr,$str);
```

`$r` should be "bb" for all of those. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: 1. What should it do if it finds aa and bb? 2. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr=array('aa','bb','cc');
$str='A_STRING_bb_WITH_SOME_TEXT aa';


function find_which_one(array $arr,$str) {
    $r = preg_match(
        '/((' . implode(')|(', $arr) .'))/',
        $str,
        $matches
    );
    return ($r !== false) ? $matches[0] : $r;
}

$r=find_which_one($arr,$str);
var_dump($r);
```

Returns false if not found, else the value from $arr that occurred first

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function find_which_one($arr,$str){
  foreach($arr AS $needle){
    if (strpos($str, $needle)){
      return true; //returns true on the first match
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the correct `key`. If not found, it will return `false`.

```
function find_which_one($keys,$value) {
  foreach($keys as $key) if (strpos($value, $key)) return $key;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: it answers the problem which is asked by the question. He actually asked for the key to be returned, not true or false. The base logic is same.

Comment: Ah yeah now I see there is really a BIG difference. thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) it is straight forward:

```
$arr = array('aa','bb','cc');
$str = 'A+STRING+bb+WITH+SOME+TEXT';

print_r ( array_filter($arr, function($k) use($str) { 
                 return strpos($str, $k) !== FALSE; }) );
Array
(
    [1] => bb
)
```

Or else:

```
$str = 'ASTRINGbbWITHSOMETEXT';
print_r ( array_filter($arr, function($k) use($str) { 
                 return strpos($str, $k) !== FALSE; }) );
Array
(
    [1] => bb
)
```